# multiple QTimer slow

Tags: qt, opengl, opencv, qtimer

I have a problem with using many QTimer in my application which uses Qt and OpenGL and OpenCV.
I have a timer1 which call a function to draw 2d image in a window and the timer2 to call a function to draw 3d content in another window in the Qt widget, but when the program run, the interaction with opengl window is very slow (~10 fps or less) and the 2d image is slow too.
What should I do?

Comment: What timer intervals are you using?

Comment: Is it only slow when interacting with the viewport?  Because `QTimer`s use the event system, so mouse dragging for example, will flood the queue with events 'stalling' the timer ones.

Comment: @Roku : I used timer->start() (0 in time interval).@cmannett85 : is there a any solution to smooth the interaction with the viewport?

Comment: Is using the mouse actually triggering a viewport update, or is it just setting the camera's view/projection matrix ready for the next update?

Comment: The two in the same time, the viewport shows vertices that should be updated at least 24 fps.

Comment: In the `QGLWidget` docs, it recommends connecting the timer's `timeout()` signal to the `updateGL()` slot, rather than just `update()` as this will bypass the Qt painting queue.  Have you done this?

Comment: @cmanett85 : no. I will try it, I'll keep you updated. Thank you.

Comment: Timer interval 0 means drawing as fast as possible. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: @Roku : Yes I want to draw image that comes from camera.

Comment: Then you should only draw when you get a new image from the camera, not "as fast as possible".